# Realm Swift query similar strings

Tags: swift, realm, nspredicate

Is it possible to make a search engine that indentifies misspelled strings using Realm queries?

For example, if there exists in my database an object with a name property “King of the Jungle,” and I have a query that check if the user’s `UISearchBar` text input. If a user types “King of,” it works because I use `CONTAINS` in my predicate. Is it possible to make it where if the user misspells something or writes something like “King Jungle” it would still return that object? Like if the string has at least a 80% accuracy rate, it would return the object.

Comment: Sounds dirty but you can fetch the whole list then do your filter logic on a Swift array.

Comment: Sure, that would be super easy. Just query for all strings that contain "King" AND "of". Is there something more? You could use a compound predicate but that may be overkill.

Comment: @Jay But what if it’s misspelled?

Comment: If you're attempting to create a spell checker, that's a task in itself, and you need to use RegEx matching and some other technologies. That would go beyond the scope of what we can answer here on SO

Comment: Another thought - you cold simply perform a close match. In other words, find entries in your database that have 1 or more matching words. For example if they typed 'King Jingle' instead of 'King Jungle, return 'King of the Jungle' since one match was found.